# Error:No provider for NoopInterceptorService! in angular 4.3.6?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I wrote a simple interceptor "NoopInterceptorService"
but I get a error "No provider for NoopInterceptorService!" ,
What could be the cause?
how to resolve it?

[image: code1]

[image: code2]

[image: code3]

Comment: did you imported HttpClientModule in your root module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services) should help how to write interceptors.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**PLuggin in**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: 
              AngularInterceptor, multi: true } ]
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: When I add provide "HTTP_INTERCEPTORS" I shall get a error "No provider for NoopInterceptorService!"
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AngularInterceptor, multi: true }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to implement INTERCEPTOR, you've to use `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpModule` for any http call.

Now, the implementation:

In your App.module.ts file, import:

```
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
```

And in the import array of you `AppModule` add the following:

```
  imports: [
      .
      HttpClientModule,
       .
  ]
```

Your providers array and `NoopInterceptorService` implementation seems to be correct. But, the important this is, whenever you'll use http method in any of your component code then don't forget to use http method of `HttpClientModule` instead of old `HttpModule`.

I think if you follow this your INTERCEPTORS will work.

Comment: That's what I wrote，but I get a error "No provider for NoopInterceptorService!"